# OnComplete in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, action, commandbutton

I have some confusion on the `Oncomplete` event in JSF. I am using primefaces.

Here is what I have in the XHTML :-

```
<p:commandButton id="createFruitBag" value="Create Fruit Bag" styleClass="ui-priority-primary create-fruit-button" rendered="#{(fruitShoppingEvent.fruitBean.Status eq 'Shopped') and  authenticatedUser.UserType() ne 'guest'}"
                    actionListener="#{OrderShopEvent.returnBag}"  oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; args.validationFailed) { resultDlg(status,args); } "
                     tabindex="520"                     
                     />
```

The actionListener is triggered and the code goes into the function - returnBag()

But in the same Oncomplete if I have an else clause , that is, if validation is true (returned from the actionListener) the code should go to the checkOut page, and if it is false then it should call the javascript function. But when the else is set, the code never goes into the actionListener, it goes directly to the checkOut page.

My else is something like this -

```
oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; args.validationFailed) { resultDlg(status,args); }  else { #{OrderShopEvent.redirectToCO()} } "
```

My question is :-
1 - Is the onComplete firing for the render, or for the click?
2 - If I want it to fire only for the click how do I handle it?

I have gone through detailed examples @BaluC and others, but I cannot understand this clearly.

Thank you very much.

.

Comment: Please re-read your question and format it correctly. Also improve your title and tags

Comment: Where did you get the impresssion you could call a java method in the oncomplete? It is for javascript calls...

Comment: The code does go into the Java function if the else part is set. Can you please let me know as to WHEN the Oncomplete is triggered, after the button is rendered, or after the click event. Thank you.

Comment: After the ajax call is completed.  And no, it will not call the java code at that moment 1000% not.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will test it by putting in an alert in the javascript. But I can tell you I have been debugging this all day, it never goes into the actionListener if that else block is there pointing to the redirectCO.